# Be notified of control changed with {emitEvent: false}

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I was trying to create a tool to display errors of a formControl. Basically, my goal was to provide inside my custom CVA a config such as

```
  <custom-control
   [errorConfig]="[
      { name: 'required', message: 'Email is required' },
      { name: 'email', message: 'Email is invalid' }
   ]"
  ></custom-control>
```

and to have proper error picked up and displayed.

I've done it through subscribing to control's `statusChanges` event and it works perfectly except for 1 thing: when value is changes with `{ emitEvent: false }`, `statusChanges` will never be called.

I understand this is intended to not have this eventEmitter called, when you set `emitEvent: false`, but is there any way to overcome this?
Is there a way to be notified about `setError/patchValue/updateValueAndValidity` methods are called with `emitEvent: false`?
Or maybe anyone has an idea to what else can I listen to update displayed error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there's a way to implement `Validator` from `@angular/forms`. It has `validate` method, that is called even if event emission is disabled.